# Axis2 Client: avoid to maintain sessions

Tags: web-services, session, client, apache-axis

I have a big problem in Axis2 client implementation.
I've generated the source code of my client (Java) through the Intellij Idea IDE from a wsdl file.
I use the client to connect in https with a webserver using a smartcard, in which is stored the certificate for the authentication.
Using the first smartcard, everything works fine: I receive data from the webservice in the right way. Using the second smartcard, I receive data related to first smartcard owner.
Analyzing the logs of my application, I've noticed that, at the end of the first communication, a session has been saved. So, in the second connection, the authentication is not needed and data is related to first smartcard owner.

Googling around, I've found that, to avoid to maintain sessions in Axis2 clients, it is needed to set the following:

```
currentStub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setManageSession(false);
```

But it does not work properly.

Anyone has suggestions?

Comment: Make sure that the client does not cache any connections by changing the HTTP headers returned to the client?

Answer (score 0):

I know, this question is quite old.

You could just create a new Stub. This should not have any reference to the old connections/sessions.